# Difference between String.getBytes() and Charset.encode()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write a library for android to encode and decode data.

Firstly I used `Charset.defaultCharset().encode("Panagos").array();` and as the result I had the below sequence of bytes

> byte[0] = 80
> byte[1]  = 97
> byte[2]  = 110
> byte[3]  = 97
> byte[4] = 103
> byte[5]  = 111
> byte[6]  = 115
> byte[7]  = 0
> byte[8] = 0
> byte[9]  = 0
> byte[10] = 0
> byte[11] = 0
> byte[12] = 0
> byte[13] = 0

and I noticed that the returned array had 7 extra 0 in the end.

Next I used `"Panagos".getBytes();` and the result was

> byte[0] = 80
> byte[1]  = 97
> byte[2]  = 110
> byte[3]  = 97
> byte[4] = 103
> byte[5]  = 111
> byte[6]  = 115

and I don't know the reason.

So could you explain me (or to help me how to google) what are the differences between `Charset.defaultCharset().encode().array();` and `String.getBytes();` methods?

Thank you in advance,
Panagiotis

Comment: On Android the default encoding is UTF-8. To make data and software portable better use `Charset charset = Charsets.fromName("UTF-8")` and `getBytes("UTF-8")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `Charset.encode()` returns a `ByteBuffer`, and `ByteBuffer.array()` returns the **whole** internal array, with zeroes in the end if the backing array is bigger than the contents of the buffer.

So which method to use? If you're working with `Buffers`, then `Charset.encode()` is useful. If you're working with arrays, then you'll want to use `String.getBytes(charset)`.